# && operator in ruby

Tags: ruby

I was going through some code written for authentication. I couldn't understand the use of `&&` in the following statement:

```
user = user_token && User.find_by_authentication_token(user_token.to_s)
```

I tried using rails console and irb. In both, they returned the second value. Can anyone explain me why it is used?

Comment: to ensure `user_token` is not nil

Comment: yes, but shouldn't && operator return true or false ??

I am really new to ruby and rails, so I might have missed some basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that `&&` is a logic-like operator, but it doesn't mean it will return true or false. The main feature here is that right-hand operation is not executed if the left-hand expression evaluates to falsy value. You can think about it this way: it is not evaluated because it is not needed to know the logical value of the `&&` expression - if the left-hand expresion is falsy, `falsy && anything` is falsy so there's no need to evaluate the right-hand expression.

Since in ruby every expression returns the value of last executed sub-expressions (not really the thing, but will help you understand the concept), `expr1 && expr2` will return value of `expr1` if it's falsy (as `expr2` is not evaluated) or value of `expr2` if `expr1` is truthy. Naturally you can chain expressions using both `&&` or `||`.

In case of `||` the logic is the same - do not evaluate RH expression, if LH expression value is sufficient to determine falseness of a whole expression. In case of `||` if the right hand expression is truthy, the whole expression is truthy regardless of RH, so it is commonly used for setting up defaults:

```
variable = options[:key] || 'Default if options[:key] is false or nil'
```

Comment: wow!!! awesome explanation :).. you just cleared all my doubts... want to up vote this one ..but don't have enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

This can be re-written as

```
if user_token.nil?
  user = nil
else
  user = User.find_by_authentication_token(user_token.to_s)
end
```

Therefore in that code we just ensure that the `user_token` is set, is not `nil`.

Comment: got it .. thanks alot :),  .. looks like I need to do the basics again :|